# typedef expected call-signature error for Angular2 tutorial with VS2015

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm doing the Angular2 tutorial in VS2015 and am stuck with a warning that is preventing one of my TypeScript files from compiling. Tutorial link as follows.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

The warning is code **typedef** with description **expected call-signature: 'getHeroes' to have a typedef**.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { HEROES } from "./mock-heroes";

@Injectable()

export class HeroService {
    getHeroes() {
        return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
    }
}
```

I have done some searching but couldn't find anything that made sense to me... i'm pretty new and learning...

Could someone help me out with how I should change the TypeScript code above to set the return type definition for the Promise returned by the getHeroes method.

Comment: i cant see any getHeroes in your file ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out... needed to import Hero and then set the function return type to **Promise**.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { HEROES } from "./mock-heroes";
import { Hero } from "./hero";

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
    }
}
```